# What is the most reliable (means IE 6 compatible ) way maintain the position of a DIV exactly at the bottom of the browser window?

Tags: html, css

What is the best way maintain the position of a DIV exactly at the bottom of the browser window?

An example is the gray social media box exactly at the bottom of browser in the following link:

http://www.zdnet.com/android-vs-windows-now-the-battle-for-the-desktop-really-begins-7000025027/

It works well after browser window re-size.

Thank  you,

Update: 
I personally don't think CSS positioning is the the best solution since there are many issues with IE 6 or 7.
I think the best option should be JavaScript or JQuery. 
I don't think the example I provided uses CSS. I think I uses JavaScript. 
I hope someone can shed some light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use inspect elements on that object you can see the code that is currently working

```
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 z-index: 4;
```

Comment: Does this work in IE7?. Do you know any remedy that make it working in IE7?

Comment: I would think that this works in IE7 but i have no way to actually test it. It isnt any CSS3 or anything so my guess would be it would.